# Changing Qutebrowser Startpage in config.py

Tags: python, browser, configuration, config

I want to set my startpage in the `config.py` file, so I can sync that file to my other devices and have the same configuration. I tried adding the line `url.start_pages = 'https://web.whatsapp.com/'` to the file, but it gives the error message

```
Errors occurred while reading config.py: 
Unhandled exception: name 'url' is not defined
```

when starting qutebrowser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably isn't the best place for qutebrowser questions, as it's not really related to programming. There are definitely better ways to [get help](https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser#getting-help)!

That being said: qutebrowser defines a global `c` object you need to set settings on, i.e. this should be `c.url.start_pages` - see the examples in the [configuring docs](https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/blob/master/doc/help/configuring.asciidoc).

Comment: Do you know whether there's any Stack-Exchange site suitable for that kind of question?  I looked at the help section that you linked. I think asking the questions on those channels makes it harder for users with the same question to find this answer.

Comment: @user6105651 [Super User](https://superuser.com/) would probably be a good place ("Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users."). Still, you'd reach a lot more qutebrowser users via the [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/qutebrowser/) which is also searchable.